# Calculate mean value for each raster and convert output array to data frame

Tags: raster, r

How do I calculate mean value for each raster and convert output array to data frame?

```
r <- as.data.frame(cellStats(x,mean))
```

Comment: I actually made a raster stack, 's <- as.data.frame(cellStats(r,mean))'thanks @atmycpu. Now I only need the stats to be done on values ranging from -1 to 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that a call to "data.frame" is all you need. If you have several rasters, just stack them. If you want the rasters as columns and the statistic as rows you can just transpose on the fly (see second example)

```
library(raster)
x <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
( x.stats <- data.frame(x.mean=cellStats(x, "mean")) )

# Combine multiple statistics as rows
( x.stats <- t(data.frame(x.mean=cellStats(x, "mean"))) )
( x.stats <- rbind(x.stats, t(data.frame(x.sd=cellStats(x, "sd")))) )
```

Comment: What if your aim is to find the mean for every 12 images (12 months in a year) in a sequence and save the output?

Answer (score 2):

to loop through a list of raster file paths:

```
library(raster) #load raster package

rasterlist <- list("path 1","path 2",...) #create list of raster file paths
outlist <- list() #create empty list to store outputs from loop

for (i in 1:length(rasterlist)) { #for each raster in rasterlist
   r <- raster(rasterlist[[i]]) #read element i of rasterlist into R
   val <- getValues(r) #get raster values
   m <- mean(val,na.rm=T) #remove NAs and compute mean
   outlist[[i]] <- c(rasterlist[[i]],m) #store raster path with mean
   return("complete")
}

df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,outlist)) #convert list to data frame
colnames(df) <- c("raster path","mean")
```